# Wordpress Rest Api access the header and extract stylesheets URL

Tags: css, javascript, rest-api

Good morning,
i have just started to see in depth the WordPress API and the use of the fetch function in javascript and i would like to know if there is the possibility to get the url of the stylesheet that refers to the block (block-library/style.min.css) so that when the WordPress installation is updated, the url and the styles to which it refers are also updated. is this possible in any way?
thanks.

Comment: Do you mean over the REST API or in PHP? In PHP all the stylesheets should be emitted by wp_head(). You could set up an API endpoint to return all the registered CSS too if you want.

Comment: @Rup i mean on REST API, currently using Wordpress as a Headless CMS